# How to parse custom scalars in graphql-codegen / apollo client?

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

The `ethers.js` library provides the `BigNumber` type. To create a `BigNumber` from a `string` we call `BigNumber.from("42")`

I have created a`GraphQLScalar` called `GraphQLBignumber` on my server:

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { BigNumber } from 'ethers';

const EthersBigNumberType = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'BigNumber',
  description: 'A custom scalar type for representing ethers.js BigNumber values',
  parseValue(value: string | number | BigNumber) {
    return BigNumber.from(value);
  },
  serialize(value: BigNumber) {
    // Serialize the BigNumber instance into a string
    return value.toString();
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    // Parse the ast value into a BigNumber instance
    if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING || ast.kind === Kind.INT || ast.kind === Kind.FLOAT) {
      return BigNumber.from(ast.value);
    }
    return null;
  },
});
```

Now I would like to use this `BigNumber` scalar on my client using `graphql-codegen`. In my `codegen.yml` I add:

```yaml
plugins:
// other plugins incl typescript etc.
  - 'add':
      content: 'import {BigNumber} from "ethers"'
scalars:
  BigNumber: 'ethers.BigNumber'
```

Now if I have the query:

```
  query GetBalance($address: String!) {
    balance(address: $address)
  }
```

And I use codegen to generate the code, the output of `GetBalanceQuery` returns an `ethers.BigNumber`

When I use my application I am not getting any errors (so far) and everything seems to be working just fine.

My question is: How does my client application know how to convert the server response in to a ethers.BigNumber? As far as I can tell the client does not have a copy of the `parseValue` function yet the server is sending the `BigNumber` as a string so somewhere `BigNumber.from(...)` needs to be called...

Comment: Don't suppose you ever figured this out?

Comment: @DanielPorteous unfortunately not... if you do, please post the answer